# Dynamic HLS segment filename using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Is is possible to change the segment filename while ffmpeg is running?

If I put this into my terminal

```
custom="event-type1"
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "rtsp://192.168.7.88/axis-media/media.amp?resolution=640x480" -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_segment_filename camera%03d-${custom}-.ts camera.m3u8 &
```

This will run in the background, creating a `camera.m3u8` file and `camera000-event-type1-.ts`, `camera001-event-type1-.ts` etc... files.

But if I then run this

```
custom="event-type2"
```

The segment files still contain "event-type1" in the name. I would like it to change to "event-type2" after I update the custom variable.

I have a separate program running that monitors the stream. I want to update the filename based on certain conditions. Is there any way to have ffmpeg to re-read the segment_filename input?

Comment: Why not just have your other program handle the renaming?

Comment: Not possible with ffmpeg.